# how to find unique users with latest message from a message table in SQLAlchemy Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, chatbot

I have a message table which stores conversations between 2 users. Structure of the table is as given below:

[image]

Some of the data are given in the following table:

[image]

So I want to write a function which will provide me unique user with their last message. For example, for the above data table, the function will return the following json.

[
{"mobile":"01675571522", "last_message":"Why you can't give correct answere"},
{"mobile":"01773289045", "last_message":"Amr 01773289045 aii number a kikiBankasia account open kora ase"}
]

How can I do this in SQLAlchemy ORM in python?

### My Trying:

I have currently do this using the following code:

```
users_set = set()
list_of_users = []
lst_msg_list = []
users = ChatResponseDB.read_all()
users_list = PreProcess.get_chat_history_list(users)

for item in users_list:
     chat_history = ChatResponseDB.read_response_by_user(item['mobile_number'])
     string_value = str(chat_history[-1])
     string_value = string_value[2:30] + '...'
     lst_msg_list.append(string_value)
     users_set.add(item['mobile_number'])
```

This approach is taking 10-12 second. How can I do better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain sql and execute it in sqlalchemy like that (I assume that table name is `chat_response`):

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

stmt = """select 
   mobile_number, concat(substring(response, 1, 30), '...')
   from (    
      select 
      response,
      mobile_number,
      row_number() over (partition by mobile_number order by date_value desc) as row_no 
      from chat_response
   ) A
   where row_no = 1
"""
serialized = []
results = session.execute(text(stmt))
for mobile_number, last_message in results:
    serialized.append({
        "mobile_number": mobile_number,
        "last_message": last_message
    })
```

Of course you can rewrite it into sqlalchemy syntax, but it probably do not add great value.